# Rotation matrix to_euler, Euler angle decomposition order reversed?

Tags: python, transforms, matrix

Is Blender's euler decomposition order reversed from common convention? I have written some code below that demonstrates this, and am wondering if I'm making a mistake.

I'm having trouble understanding the Euler angle decomposition order when defining a rotation matrix manually, via the python api, and then using matrix.to_euler() (from mathutils). I want to do an 'XYZ' euler decomposition, which in common convention assumes a rotation matrix composed of Rx * Ry * Rz (eg. [see wikipedia page on Rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix))

Wikipedia also lists how to decompose angles x, y, and z (alpha, beta, and gamma) from the rotation  matrix: 
[image: xyz decomp from wikipedia]

However, if I use mathutils "to_euler('XYZ') on the same matrix, I do not get the same euler angles as the above implementation from wikipedia. Instead, I get these when I call to_euler('ZYX'). Hence, Blender's decomposition order seems to be reversed from common convention (for instance, wiki's implementation seems to be based on [this document](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/EulerAngles.pdf), and I can confirm that my dynamics textbook implements euler angles similarly).

Am I making a mistake, or is Blender's implementation reversed (and thus potentially confusing)?

```
import mathutils as mu
import numpy as np
import math


R = mu.Matrix([[ 0.95178465, -0.30668812, -0.00695456],
 [ 0.30676697,  0.95154004,  0.02157744],
 [ 0.,         -0.02267051,  0.99974299]])
 
 # xyz

phi_y = np.arctan2(R[0][2], math.sqrt(1 - (R[0][2])**2))  #angle beta in wiki
# or just phi_y = np.arcsin(R[0,2])
phi_x = np.arctan2(-R[1][2],R[2][2])    #angle alpha in wiki
phi_z = np.arctan2(-R[0][1],R[0][0])    #angle gamma in wiki


print('Manually computed XYZ Euler angles =')
print([phi_x, phi_y, phi_z])

print('Euler angles using to_euler function in Blender=')
print(R.to_euler('XYZ'))
print(R.to_euler('ZYX'))
```

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure the order string is in natural reading order, ie. "XYZ" means "first X, then Y, then Z". In terms of matrices of course, the first matrix applied is on the right, and the last is on the left.

Comment: I don't understand how that is the natural reading order? The to_euler('ZYX') command provides the euler decomposition of [Rx * Ry * Rz ]

Comment: XYZ order means that you rotate first around X, then around Y, then around Z axis. Natural reading order, from left to right.